# Using Markdown formatting in table using kable in quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, kable, quarto

Using quarto's HMTL-output functionalities, I am trying to produce a kable from a data.frame that contains some Markdown-style formatting that should show up in the final document. In the actual use case, I have a number of documents already formatted this way and I would like re-use these commands for correctly rendering the output.

Here's my *example.qmd*:

````
---
title: "example"
format: 
  html
---

```{r setup}
library(kableExtra)
```

```{r}
#| echo: false
data.frame(Function = "`read_delim()`",
           Formula = "$\\leftarrow$",
           Break = "this continues on a<br>new line",
           Link = "[Google](www.google.com)") |>
  kbl(format = "html") 
```
````

After running the chunk, the preview in RStudio does display the arrow and line break correctly, but ` ` and the link fail to have an effect:

[image: Screenshot from RStudio]

When rendering the qmd to HTML, the result looks like this, i.e. ignores the formatting:

[image]

What am I missing? Is there a way to include such formatting commands into a kable when rendering a quarto document to HTML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When creating a table in Quarto, you can't mix Markdown with HTML - the Markdown syntax won't be processed within the HTML table.

This R code would work

```
data.frame(Function = "`read_delim()`",
           Formula = "$\\leftarrow$",
           Break = "this continues on a<br>new line",
           Link = "[Google](www.google.com)") |>
  kbl(format = "markdown")
```

So if you can, output only Markdown table which `knitr::kable()` should do by default.

If you need to output a HTML table (e.g for specific HTML features), you need to use a framework that will render the markdown for you while creating the HTML table.

- **gt** with [`fmt_markdown()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/fmt_markdown.html) and [`md()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/md.html)
- **flextable** with **ftextra** and [`colformat_md()`](https://ftextra.atusy.net/reference/colformat_md.html) or [`as_paragraph_md`](https://ftextra.atusy.net/reference/as_paragraph_md.html)

This is possible that this limitation of note being able to include raw Markdown inside HTML table will be improve in the future (https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/957#discussioncomment-2807907)

Comment: Thank you, `format = "markdown"` was the part I've been looking for!