# print markdown table when creating word doc using quarto

Tags: r, markdown, quarto

In my notebook I have some R code like this taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516135/using-markdown-formatting-in-table-using-kable-in-quarto):

```
#| echo: false

data.frame(Function = "`read_delim()`",
           Formula = "$\\leftarrow$",
           Break = "this continues on a<br>new line",
           Link = "[Google](www.google.com)") |>
  kbl(format = "markdown")
```

This produces output as Markdown but it is also Markdown in the final word document I create like this:

```
quarto render SomeNB.ipynb --to docx --execute
```

How can I create a code generated table in this use case?

PS:

The current output in the word doc looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you not have the `#| echo: false` part from the linked question? What exactly does your notebook code look like?

Comment: thanks - I forgot this but even with I get the edited outputs ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using `output: docx`. For me it works as expected.

Comment: I use: quarto render SomeNB.ipynb --to docx --execute maybe that's the issue?